# Connection timed out ftp cannot connect

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ftp

I have a ubuntu server and am trying to connect using filezilla but keep getting connection timed out.

I have done an nmap and the port that is opened for ftp is 21.

I have gone onto the server and done an ftp on localhost and it works fine.

I have also tried to ftp via terminal command but connection times out on there as well.

Not sure what else i can do allow ftp?

Comment: -1 For using FTP. Sorry, call my insensitive, but there is no good reason to be using such an insecure, inefficient, broken protocol. Use scp/sftp instead.

Comment: It wasn't your question, and I'm not going to downvote you, but EEAA is right that scp/sftp is better.  (Because FTP is insecure.)

Comment: @KatherineVillyard - sometimes a downvote seems to be the only way to get people's attention around here. :) Honestly though, I'm so sick of seeing people asking about technologies that have no business in modern sysadmin (cPanel/webmin/etc. also fall into this category), that I've just started downvoting them carte blanche. Maybe that's inappropriate, but whatever, it's worth losing a few rep points for.

Comment: Cheers guys but still timing out

Comment: @tjhack - so then ditch FTP and use a proper, secure file transfer protocol like scp. You will have **none** of these issues with scp/sftp.

Comment: @tjhack SFTP = SSH port (22).  One shot one kill.  BAM!  No passwords flying around unencrypted, either!  It's win/win.

Comment: cool have configured that on the sshd port which is 22 but now authenticated error. Have checked the password and username is all is correct. Authentication failed.
Error: Critical error
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: @tjhack - Great! Ask that as a separate question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the firewall on the client machine, or set the mode to passive.

There are actually two separate connections, a data channel and a command channel.  It's common for the data channel to be blocked by the client machine's firewall.

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699163/2409749) explains it well.

The comment thread above reminds me that I should probably point out that FTP isn't secure.  Unless you have a business reason that requires FTP, you might want to consider SCP or SFTP instead.  (Bonus:  They don't include the port wackiness that you're running into.)